# Compare date with current date by providing format

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have tried following lines of code

```
var formatToApply = "DD/MM/YYYY"
if(moment(dobfield, formatToApply).isAfter(moment(now, formatToApply))) 
{
    swal({
        title: "",
        text: "Date of birth has to be in the past! "
    });
    $("#dobfield").focus();
}
```

It is throwing error message "now not defined" in console...
How to apply format to present date in moment.js

Comment: use `now()` instead of `now` or you can also get current time using this `moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this;

```
moment().format(formatToApply);
```